# Conditional IF statement not returning true even though echo of $user->province is correct

Tags: conditional-tags, wp-user-query

I am having a problem with an if statement which I have now tested many times over.

```
        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Subscriber' ) );

        if ( !empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
            foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {

                echo $user->province . '<br/>'; // this outputs the province as expected, i.e. Free State


                if ($user->province == 'Free State') { // This does not return true, even though the echo above works
                    echo '<strong>' . $user->company_name . '</strong> <br/>';
                    echo $user->town. '<br/>';
                    echo $user->province. '<br/>';
                }


        } else {
            echo 'There are currently no photographers for this region.';
        }
```

}

I basically only wanting to show photographers in a certain province.
Many thanks.

Comment: I see there isn't a correct closing parenthesis for "foreach" loop, can you please verify this

Comment: @MarutiMohanty, fixed it. Copy and paste issue

Comment: It happens, use a better editor/IDE to avoid anything such in future.

Comment: have you checked that `$user->province` does not have any unwanted space characters?

Comment: How do I check that @Michael? Other than echoing out the output? I do see in the developer toolbar that Free State is wrapped in quotes like this "Free State"

Comment: try to output: `echo 'x'.$user->province.'x';` 
or in your conditional, try to use: `if ( trim($user->province) == 'Free State') {`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
if ($user->province == 'Free State') {
```

to:

```
if ($user->province === 'Free State') {
```

Comment: How will this make a difference?

Comment: I've had unexpected results on strings using == and tend to use === in such instances.
On 2nd thoughts, it would be more likely to work with == than === so apologies for that. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: It's good practice to use `===` as it also checks for the type of that variable. But for non empty strings it won't make any difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281664/should-one-use-strict-comparison-in-strings

Comment: Thanks Tom but that didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

First I would make sure the output on the echo is exactly as you suspect by wrapping it in `<pre>` tags, then viewing source on the front end to make sure there are no other special characters involved.

I notice that this post, http://tommcfarlin.com/wp_user_query/ uses `$user_query->get_results();` instead of `$user_query->results;` maybe give that a try?

I've always had problems with doing if statements by name and where possible use id's instead. But it doesn't sound like that is possible here :/